# What is a word to describe the units of influences for a piece of work?

Tags: vocabulary

The thing about a changelog, or an update that has been made for a document or an app, is by the time the reader reads about the update or the change, the update's already happened. The reader is now reading about the past, not the the present.

So this unit of change, from the perspective of the author, is an update, but from the perspective of the reader in the future, it's no longer an update. It's ... what? A completed change?

Another example. The science of evolution has received many contributions, including from Charles Darwin. We would not look at this branch of science and say Charles Darwin made an update. From the perspective of the 21st century... this branch of science has many.... sources. Influences. etc.

Sources and influences are the best words I've thought of so far but they don't sound quite right to me.

Basically I'm looking for a word like update except the word communicates it's already happened and it's helped create what exists now.

Comment: To application users, no matter how far distant they are from the change, the update is still an update, because the application was updated.

Comment: That mingling of the two concepts in "influences" and "sources" is not clear; this has to be put differently because when you say that something has influences you mean "influences wielded by that something" and not "influences that contributed to give rise to it".

Comment: Aren't those changes called revisions?

Comment: @YosefBaskin A revision refers to something in the present. If a document or codebase has a revision from 10 months ago, in order to "understand" that revision, you have to jump your mind back 10 months ago. I'm looking for a word that allows you to stay in the present while still understanding that revision as though it occured 10 months ago.

Comment: @FeliniusRex check out my reply to Yosef. I think it'll help you understand what I mean

Comment: @YosefBaskin Think of the word person and the word ancestor, what is the equivalent of the word ancestor for update/version/revision/change/etc?

Comment: @LPH ya I was thinking about that too, I agree. I mean the latter one, what influences led an artist or an author or a philosopher to create what they ended up creating

Comment: A revision does not refer to something in the present. It refers to an action done to an item in the past. I can talk about the fifth, the tenth, the 100th revision of a work, and every one of those means an action done in the past.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Someone can easily say "I'm going to make a revision" but it's a bit awkward/funny to say "I'm going to make an ancestor"

Comment: @FeliniusRex It can be something that has been done in the past or it can be something that is done today and it can be planned to be done in the future, as countless numbers of things.

Comment: The question is based on the assumption that it is somehow self-contradictory to say that an update took place in the past. It is far from clear why the OP is making that assumption.

Comment: @jsw29 it’s completely fine to say an update took place in the past. I’m looking for a word more specific than update that clearly communicates that it’s from the past, and not something currently being made, or something that could be made

Comment: @wooooo298103, saying that 'it’s completely fine to say an update took place in the past' seems to contradict the claim, made in the question, that 'from the perspective of the reader in the future, it's **no longer an update**'.

Comment: Another example is student vs alumnus. A new student could join, a school has students, and a school has had many students. But if a school has an alumnus, it’s clearly referring to something that happened in the past, but that currently exists.

Comment: @jsw29 ah I see. That’s poor wording on my part. I meant to say “it’s no longer an update that’s being made”

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to describe the **impetus** for something.

> (SOED) **1** *fig.* Moving force, (an) impulse, a stimulus

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=M15TQ8OpfxUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22impetus+for%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIgNCPoYjuAhVFyhoKHc4zCKkQ6AEwAnoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22impetus%20for%22&f=false)) Japan in the 1990s: Crisis as an Impetus for Change

According to some new descriptions in your comments you might be intersted in the word "**prototype**".

> (SOED) **3** A trial model or  preliminary version of a vehicle, machine, etc.

Comment: This is definitely an interesitng suggestion... not quite what I'm looking for but it does get my mind jogging

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting re: prototype. I agree there’s one definition / nuance to that word that insinuates what came before what we have now. But unfortunately that word is like the word draft. It’s what’s going to come up and what could be currently going (i.e. “I’m going to make a prototype” or “I’m going to prototype that and see what that’s like”)

Comment: @wooooo298103 It's just as "revision": it does not carry any notion of time, not inherently. what it does is to imply the notion of "before in time", which is in "proto".

Answer (score 0):

A log of changes to a software program is vastly different from a history of the development of a scientific theory like evolution.

One could speak of major developments in the history of a scientific theory and of major contributors to the theory or the science.

A log of events, like a ship’s log, records events or observations as they occur. A recorded update to a software program remains an update, and a historical development remains a development.

Thus there is no single word that would seem appropriate to describe changes made to an app or a program, discoveries in science, people whose thinking influences others, and so forth.

Comment: There’s countless words in any given language that are general enough to apply across many domains. I’m well, well aware of what a log of events is, what contributions to science are, etc